# ASP.NET MVC / Javascript: VideoJS media could not be loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video

I originally started trying to use the HTML `<video>` element to play all (our hopefully almost all) mp4 videos. I quickly realized that mp4's were not actually a video encoding and really nothing more than a wrapper for video encodings. This led me to try using a more advanced control (`VideoJS` in this case) however I am still having issues playing an mp4 video. My videojs control look as follows:

```
<section>
  <video id="videoPlayer" style="margin-top:30px" width="480" height="204" controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
    <source src='@Url.Content("~/Content/AudioAssets/toystory.mp4")' type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div id="bar" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(85, 0, 0) 7.60904%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 7.60904%);" class="bar"></div>
</section>
```

I have one event handler tied in which looks as follows:

```
videojs("videoPlayer", {}, function(){
    //do some work unassociated with video control
  });
```

What am I missing here? I have read the documentation and other examples seem very similar to this one. Note that I am able to navigate to the file in windows explorer and successfully play it without issue.

The console error in chrome debugger I am receiving is the following:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: ((CODE: 4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: check MIME type for mp4 has been added to your server or not?

Comment: yes it has. in my web config I have `<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />`

Comment: Ohkkk than try to add this to IIS server i have mentioned steps in my answer

Comment: Have also tried through IIS Express. It seems the mime type is being added ok as I've now noticed I can play a select few other mp4s but most mp4s I try to play do not work

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps for adding MIME types in IIS server

1) Select the site to configure in IIS, right click and select "Properties"

2) Under HTTP Headers Tab, select "File Types" under the MIME Map section and select "New Type"

3) Type ".flv" as the associated extension and "video/x-flv" as the content type or "flv-application/octet-stream" I'm not sure on which one gives here.

4) for .mp4 files type ".mp4" as the extension and "video/mp4" as the mime type (this one I tested personally)

4) Select "OK",

5) type services.msc, find the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and click on the restart icon on top or open up and choose restart

**OR**

You can add into webconfig also as below

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
       </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I appreciate your time however I am already adding the mime type. See the comments section of my original post